# triggering JS function with appended c# string working after the second postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have this asp Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" OnClick = "OnConfirm" Text = "Raise Confirm" />
```

I have this c# code behind

```
public void OnConfirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string eventIDel = "anyStringGivenAtRunTime";


            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "DeleteUserChosenEvent", "confirmDeletion('" + eventIDel + "');", true);

            string confirmValue = confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];


            if (confirmValue == "Yes")
            {
              // Do something like
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked YES!');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked NO!');", true);
            }



    }
```

I have this JS function triggered inside the code...

code behind "trigger":

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "JumpToBottom", "confirmDeletion('" + eventIDel + "');", true);" :
```

JS Function:

```
function confirmDeletion(str) {
    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
    confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
    if (confirm("Do you want to delete Event: " + str + " ?")) {
        confirm_value.value = "Yes";
    } else {
        confirm_value.value = "No";
    }
    document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
```

The event only works fine after the 2nd Time clicked if I use a syntax like this:

```
this.btnConfirm.Attributes.Add("onclick", "confirmDeletion('" + eventIDel +  "');");
```

But if I use a syntax like the original one it starts with NULL without asking for a confirmation after which it will store the user decision on the confirm and use it for the next time user presses the button.

Please help Thanks Big Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I understood that the page cycle will always place the JS function at the end if I call it from code behind. The ideal approach was for me to call the JS function on the ASP Button, which will be triggered by default first.
ASP Button

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete"  onclick="btnDelete_Click"  class="buttons"  Visible="true"  disabled="disabled"  OnClientClick="if (!deleteRow()) return false;"  />
```

Then in the JS function I will pull the whole gridview, identified each row in my case is by a radio button selection and then extract the text of the cell I wanted like this

```
    function deleteRow() {
        // Get Gridview 
        var gridView = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>");
        // Loop through the Gridview
        for (var i = 1; i < gridView.rows.length; i++) {
            // Get the radio button of each row in the gridview and see if its checked
           if (gridView.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].checked == true)
               // Get Event ID value from 1st cell of rowReturn Answer
               return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete Event ID: " + gridView.rows[i].cells[1].innerText + "?");  
        }
    }
```

After which the return will bring the true all false that the button will handled with the following logic

```
OnClientClick="if (!deleteRow()) return false;"
```

Meaning if the user selected yes it will proceed to the C# method in charge of deleting!!!

Hurray!!!